# how view binding works in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

1. go to definition(cmd+click) click the binding class , android studio will jump to xml instead of the generated code. how does it work?
2. when i add a new layout, I don't have to build the project to get the new reference. how does android studio geneate the binding class real time?

all i want is to create some gradle plugins like that.  Generate a class and use it in realtime